# sum of the quadratic difference between two variables

Tags: r

How can I calculate the sum of the quadratic difference in *Gnu R* between two variables considering the following random data?

```
set.seed(100)

a <- sample(1:100, 10)
b <- sample(100:1, 10)
```

I have not found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the phrase "sum quadratic difference" means to you but since both the "-" and the "^" functions are vectorized, you can get:

```
> (a-b)^2
 [1]   49  169  324 3136  324   81   16 1024 1849  225
```

So if you are working with residuals you might "say":

```
> sum( resid <- (a-b)^2 )
[1] 7197
> resid
 [1]   49  169  324 3136  324   81   16 1024 1849  225
```

If instead that means summing the differences of their squares you might use:

```
> sum( resid <- a^2 - b^2 )
[1] -5149
```

Comment: This answer is the most complete. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb here and say you just want to do

```
c <- sum((a-b)^2)
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, Massa. It is indeed what I was looking for.